# Сложности ERP системы

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Недавно поступило предложение заняться разработкой ERP системы, и у меня возникло несколько вопросов.

Разработка будет проходить на ReactJS и Node.
Имею опыт разработки на ReactJs и есть техническое представления работы Node и базовые знания по ее использованию.

Не разу не сталкивался с подобной задачей и не принимал в ней участие.

*Сложно ли разработать ERP систему без должного опыта и понимания, как все должно работать, и как все должно выглядеть?*

Мне сложно дать оценку этой задаче и понять насколько сложной и трудоемкой она будет.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и ответ на него почти целиком будет заложен в сформированном тз, том какого функционала от ERP ожидает заказчик.

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что никто вам точного ответа не даст. Во-первых, представления о сложности у каждого свое, во-вторых неизвестны конечные объемы потенциальной разработки. Что вы хотите получить на выходе? Хотя бы есть понимание, что система будет *размером/сложностью, как вот %вставатьИмяДругогоПродуктаЗдесь%? А уж *"как все должно работать, и как все должно выглядеть"* - это точно повод к холивару, потому что, как минимум, может зависеть от конкретных ситуаций.

Comment: А Вы вообще представляете как строят подобные системы и серверную архитектуру, работа с БД и многопоточность на каких-то других языках?